# Support Physics Problem Solving on Area 51

Tags: discussion, area51

I know there are many Physics enthusiasts on Math SE. I would invite them to have a look at the [new site proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103955/physics-problem-solving/103964#103964)

Presently Physics SE isn't meant for problem-solving. It is more about specific physics concepts. The new site wishes to be what Physics SE isn't i.e. a platform to discuss various ways of solving a problem and helping users find out their mistakes while solving. [See the meta post on Physics SE to get a better idea.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/new-site-proposal-specifically-for-problem-solving-in-physics-on-area-51)

At the moment we lack followers on the proposal. But I think it can be a successful site. Do have a look and leave your suggestions on the meta post. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25253/220382

Comment: This is a great idea, and I hope more people support it!

Comment: Although I do not especially have interest in this proposal, there is a history of entertaining requests for Area 51 proposals with a significant (if tangential) relationship to Math.SE.  Of 25 Questions here on Meta tagged Area51, the only one which was closed as "off-topic" was so treated only after it failed (and a couple of months of discussion in Meta).

Comment: First I say that I ignore the main problem, but about that I've read I say that perhaps if is a good idea create a PhysicsOverflow site and after do a relaxation abot the site Physic Stack Exchange. I hope that previous  proposal don't disturb to you and your friends that want the best of these communities SE. I hope that my proposal is not stupid 100% from other opinions that I respect. On the other hand could be insteresting different ideas about new sites: Physics+ mathematics and/or Experiments in Physics-mathematics. Good luck.

Comment: @user243301 Physics Overflow already exists outside Stack Exchange but that is dedicated to research level physics at present...http://physicsoverflow.org/.... anyway thank you for your suggestion. Do check out the new website we are still building http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com/?qa=questions

Comment: Thanks for your information and courage!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Well, a whole lot of things have happened, but in a nutshell:

- Our proposal was closed as a duplicate.
- We got an offer from Physics Overflow to host the site. But due to some differences with Physics SE we had to decline the offer.
- @Mew is building the new site by hand outside Stack Exchange network. (Prototype: http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com/?qa=questions)

We want the relations between our new site, Physics Problems Q&A, and Physics.SE to be friendly. Hopefully, once our site is firmly established, we can establish some sort of protocol for migrating questions between sites, or at the very least recommending the other site to users. We certainly do not want a relationship like that between Physics Overflow and Physics.SE. We would be glad to welcome any users to our site; please see our first draft of our scope and guidelines to know what we expect. Moderators on the site are [@heather](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/121464/heather), [@S007](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/131786/s007?tab=profile) , and [@Mew](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/12350/mew) (username Einstein on the new site).

Our site is coming along quite well although there are still improvements to be made, both in the construction of the site and in the general guidelines. If you have any questions, the chatroom on the new site is still under construction, so please ping one of us at the Physics Stack Exchange chatrooms.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

More of an update than an answer, but there is no question.

The Physics Problem Solving Area 51 proposal has since been closed by Stack Exchange staff. A comprehensive statement about this can be found [in an answer by Robert Cartaino](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25679).

Answer (score 2):

I followed the link the Meta.Physics.SE discussion given in the Question, and tried especially to understand the dictum "Presently Physics SE isn't meant for problem-solving."

One of the Related items shown there for it is this (fairly well-upvoted and answered) previous Meta.Physics post, [Should we allow questions asking the mathematical solution to physics problems?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-allow-questions-asking-the-mathematical-solution-to-physics-problems)  It discusses voting to Close cases where problems in which "the physics is basically done" and only some math remains.

This may only be relevant here when advising Posters that their Question is off-topic for Math.SE and/or would be better posted at Physics.SE.  Some recently Closed examples:  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994905/calculate-the-equivalent-resistance-seen-from-the-e6-generator#comment4096004_1994905), where a Comment encouraged reposting at Physics.SE, and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1994986/physics-gravitational-acceleration), which did not get such a recommendation.

I've previously brought up [ill-suited alternative SE site reposting recommendations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23025/comments-that-suggest-reposting-to-an-ill-suited-se-site-to-flag-or-not-to-flag) and the nexus with recommending sites where one is not an active participant.

Since I'm not an active participant at Physics.SE, accordingly rather than simply advising the OP in the first of these linked problems that they should instead post their Question there, I located [a similar Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239188/short-circuit-in-superposition) that had already been asked and answered there (suggesting it as a model of how to ask).

Comment: See the updates please.